# TextBox text update with MultiThreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm having quite an annoying issue with Multithreading, I'm just updating a textBox with multilines inside a loop like this:

```
if (results.Lines.Count() != 0)
    this.InvokeEx(f => f.results.Text += Environment.NewLine);

this.InvokeEx(f => f.results.AppendText("0\t1"));
```

When I run this with just one Thread, all looks ok:

[image]

But when I run with multi threading (10 Threads at the same time):

[image]

It looks like that the writing in the textBox is not Synchronized, everything looks messed up.

Any way to solve this?

This with Windows Forms application with .Net Framework 4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because a thread that just wrote a new line, might be preempted by another thread about to write another new line.

You should make sure your two instructions are seen as an atomic operation. I.e., multiple concurrent operations will be seen as if they were sequential.

You do this by introducing a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) around your *critical region*.

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();

lock(_lock)
{
    if (results.Lines.Count() != 0)
        this.InvokeEx(f => f.results.Text += Environment.NewLine);

    this.InvokeEx(f => f.results.AppendText("0\t1"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the appending of the new line with the additional text to be an atomic operation.  Currently you are in no way enforcing the constraint that these two operations be performed atomically, even though you rely on it.  The easiest solution is to simply call `Invoke` once, and build up the string before doing so:

```
string textToAppend = ConstructStringToAppend();

this.InvokeEx(f => f.results.AppendText(textToAppend));
```

Now you know that the string will be written to as one atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate checking the line count every time and condense it to a one-liner:

```
this.InvokeEx(
    f => f.results.AppendText(string.Concat("0\t1", Environment.NewLine)));
```